# Saving a Unicode Text with "\n" to Oracle DB via Python SQLAlchemy cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, unicode, sqlalchemy

I am using Python SQLAlchemy cx_Oracle. And I am storing a string like this

```
"1 Some Road\nSome Place\nSome City"
```

into a db.Text field. But after saving it to it, what I get back is:

```
 "1 Some RoadSome PlaceSome City"
```

So, do you know who has eaten my "\n"s? Please help me out

Here's how I defined the model in Python:

```
class Object(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    address = db.Column(db.Text(100))
```

Here's how I saved it:

```
o = Object(address=""1 Some Road\nSome Place\nSome City")
db.session.add(o)
db.session.commit()
```

Afterwards, when I get it own, o.address is:

```
 "1 Some RoadSome PlaceSome City"
```

Cheers

Comment: That may be how it's represented in your client but it's not necessarily how it's stored in the database...

Comment: I checked using SQLdeveloper on the fields. I couldn't find '\n' either.

Answer (score 0):

try to insert you string like this:

```
insert into table_name (column_name) values ('1 Some Road' || chr(10) || 'Some Place' || chr(10) || 'Some City');
```

chr(10) represents the char with nummer 10 from ASCII Table - the 'new line'

Comment: Your answer is inspiring. I will try to replace '\n' with unicode U+000A LINE FEED (\n). and let you know

Comment: When I put in "1 Some RoadU+000ASome PlaceU+000ASome City", it didn't work in Python.

Comment: @chfw found a solution for this?

Comment: @zengr No. But I went around the problem. I translated '\n' before insertion and reversed it after retrieval.